# Throwing error message when running 'npm start' for 'create-react-app'. See the error msg below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

This is my first React project trying to resolve this error, can't seem to find a solution.
When i run 'npm start' i get the below error message.
I added a package.json to this question if that helps.
I would really appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> #!/usr/bin/env node
| 'use strict';
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.0",
    "npm": "^7.15.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",

    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So seems like there's some Node file in your source folder, which Babel is treating like a regular Javascript file (which it isn't). Need to find that one and move it outside the source folder that Babel is pointed at for front end code

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444, but i am getting other error messages now.*
``` ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js  
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);```